# Fullscreen mode working localhost but not on firebase server

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a site located at 'http://motostats.live/' and im working on a fullscreen mode which can be accessed at the top right of the page. I was using jquery and the fullscreen API to get into fullscreen which worked fine locally, also tryed angular-fullscreen again and worked fine, but soon as i uploaded to firebase free hosting it creates some frameset which i cannot drill into? well i believe this makes my fullscreen code break. Anyone got some ideas? here was my original code:

```
     function exitFullscreen(){

  $('.container').css({maxWidth: '1500px'});

  var el = $('html');

  if (el.exitFullscreen) {
    el.exitFullscreen();
  } else if (el.msExitFullscreen) {
    el.msExitFullscreen();
  } else if (el.mozCancelFullScreen) {
    el.mozCancelFullScreen();
  } else if (el.webkitExitFullscreen) {
    el.webkitExitFullscreen();
  }

  vm.fullscreen   = false;
}

function goFullscreen(){

  var el = $('html');

  $('.container').css({maxWidth: '100%'});

  if (el.requestFullscreen) {
    el.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (el.msRequestFullscreen) {
    el.msRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (el.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    el.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (el.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    el.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  }

  vm.fullscreen = true;

}
```

Link to the github of angular-fullscreen: https://github.com/fabiobiondi/angular-fullscreen

Also here is the top of my page once loaded and online with firebaseapp
[image: Also here is the top of my page once loaded and online with firebaseapp]